# estimate of solution of initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $ \phi : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R $ a continuous function. Prove that the initial value problem

$$ y' =y + \phi (x) e^{ -y^{2}} ; \quad y(0)=1$$

has a unique solution on the real line.

(ii) If $ y$ is the unique solution prove that

$$ | y(x) -e^{x} | \leq ( e^x -1) \max_{ 0 \leq t \leq x} | \phi (t) | \quad \forall x>0 .$$

---

I have prove that there is a unique solution but I can't prove the inequality in (ii).

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hints:*

- Write down a differential equation for $u(x) = y(x) - e^x$.
- For $0\leq t \leq x$, $$\left|\phi(t) e^{-y^2}\right| \leq  \max_{ 0 \leq t \leq x} | \phi(x)|. $$

Spoiler below:

> $$u' = u + \phi(x) e^{-y^2}, u(0)=0,$$
>
>  You can get the estimates for $u(x)$ from the fact that $u'=u + f(x)$ has the solution $$ u(x) =e^{x} \int_0^x e^{-t} f(t) dt $$
>  here $f(x) = \phi(x) e^{-y^2}$.
>
>  We have $$\left|\int_0^x e^{-t} f(t) dt\right| \leq \max_{ 0 \leq t \leq x} | \phi(x)| \int_0^x e^{-t}  dt = \max_{ 0 \leq t \leq x} | \phi(x)| (1- e^{-x}).$$
>  Thus,
>  $$ |u(x)| \leq \max_{ 0 \leq t \leq x} | \phi(x)|  (e^{x} -1).$$

Comment: Can you explain how did you find $ u_{ \max} $...?

Comment: I hope it is now better understandable?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! Nice solution! Every step in now clear to me!

Comment: Just one small question: Is this a general way to attack problems like this one, where we need to estimate the quantity $ | y(x) - e^x|$ ( where $y$ is a solution to a initial valu problem)...?

Comment: Yes. See above :-) (write down an equation/solution for $y-e^x$ and estimate)

Comment: Nice! Thank you once again!

Comment: @ Fabian:  very nice, +1.  What's the (Latex or other) code for that "spoiler" trick?

Comment: @RobertLewis: thanks! The spoiler trick is e.g. explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers).